# packaging kivy application to android

Tags: android, python, sqlite, kivy

I never had a problem compiling my kivy applications before(done it many times) but i have one now : it throws the application normally on my Phone but when i open it it freezes on the presplash icon and gives me a message : **"could not extract public data".** i thought it was my sqlite3 file.
So i have changed its name and added to `./distribute.sh -m "sqlite3 kivy"` and still have the problem.my build.py looks like this:

```
./build.py --dir /home/toufic/Desktop/Pay4 --name "Lebanese PayCalc" --package org.demo.PayCalc --version 1.2.4 --icon /home/toufic/Desktop/Pay4/lp.png --presplash /home/toufic/Desktop/Pay4/onmyown.png --permission INTERNET --permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --window debug installd
```

---

if i try to compile it with buildozer i have the following error :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in <lambda>
    return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
bsddb.db.DBPageNotFoundError: (-30985, 'DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found')
```

in my main.py file i have the following dependencies:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from net_pay_oop import * # it's a class i have written and using its instance in  my code
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import sqlite3
import datetime
import os
import math
import smtplib
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
import sys
```

long story short i need the right way to compile it either with python-for-android or the Buildozer utility(i'm new to this). can anyone please help according to the modules that i am using or is there a way to debug the build and know where the problem hides?

Edit: so I kind of made the app open but SMTP services at not working. Should I do ./distribute.sh "openssl sqlit3 kivy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to smtp services to be enabled was to includ in distribute.sh the openssl option but still the error dispayed by my device : **"could not extract public data"** was not solved. i guess it is an sqlite3 issue but the thing is that this only happens upon first installation and my application loads normally afterwards and displays all saved data and browses them normally.